# Check a specific field in a firebase document and return the document ID if field is found?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I want to return the document id if the field in the document matches what I need. I have tried this so far.

[image]

```
final result = await queueCollection.where('patientID', isEqualTo: uid).getDocuments();
print(result.documents);
return result;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the elements from the database that correspond to your `result` query, then you should use a `stream`, like in the following lines of code:

```
 Widget _build(BuildContext context) {
 return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
   stream: queueCollection.where('patientID', isEqualTo: uid).snapshots(),
   builder: (context, snapshot) {
     if (!snapshot.hasData) {
       return LinearProgressIndicator();
     }

     var snapshots = snapshot.data.documents;
     //Do what you need to do with the data

     //return a ListView for example
   },
 );
}
```

Please note that `snapshots` is an object of type `List<DocumentSnapshot>`. Now simply iterate over the list and get each `DocumentSnapshot` element out of it. Once you have it, simply get the `patientID` like this:

```
var patientID = userDocument["patientID"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should consider which method returns what in Firebase platform. `getDocument()` returns multiple documents if there are any. Your `result` variable holds `QuerySnapshot` now. You can iterate over every document with this code.

```
result.documents.forEach((DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot ){
    print(documentSnapshot.data);
});
```